# Strange behaviour of for_each and push_back()

Tags: c++11, foreach, lambda

I was doing some testing with for_each and the use of lambda functions and I'm stuck on this (compiled with g++ -std=c++11, gcc version 5.3.1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> vi = {1,1,1,1};
    int end =0;

    cout << "vi contains: ";
    for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(),[](int i){
        cout << i << " ";
    });
    cout << endl;

    for_each(vi.begin(),vi.end(),[&](int i){
        cout << "i="<<i<<" ";
        if(i==1){
            vi.push_back(1);
            end++;
        }
    });

    cout << endl;
    cout << "end=" << end << endl;
    cout << "now vi contains: ";

    for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(),[](int i){
        cout << i << " ";
    });
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output of this code

```
vi contains: 1 1 1 1 
i=1 **i=0** i=1 i=1 
end=3
now vi contains: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

why is, at the first iteration of the loop, i equal to 0?

Comment: You're modifying a vector while iterating over it, what invalidates iterators

Comment: so is not possible to add (or remove) elements to(of) a vector with for_each, is it right?

Comment: using 

/*for(vector<int>::const_iterator i=vi.begin(); i<vi.end() && end!=4; i++)
{
 if(*i==1) {vi.push_back(1); end++;}
}*/

works correctly

Comment: Don't use iterators if you must modify the collection

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki ok understood thank you!

Comment: @SbabZ That loop only appears to work. Perhaps you got lucky and `vi` has enough spare capacity, so that `push_back` happens not to need to reallocate memory and invalidate all iterators. Or, `push_back` did and did, and the rest of the loop works with a wild iterator. The difference between the explicit loop and `for_each` is that the latter in this scenario would have *two* wild iterators - the current one and what used to be `vi.end()` - so the undefined behavior may manifest differently. But either way, the behavior is in fact undefined.